# Jupyter + Apache Toree Kernel error on Windows 10

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I get a kernel error when I am creating a Jupyter notebook with the Apache Toree - Scala kernel. Here is the stack trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 243, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 123, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\darie\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Some more details about my setup:

I am running the Jupyter Notebook using the latest version of Anaconda(4.4.0). 
I installed Apache Toree following these commands:

```
pip install https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/toree/0.2.0/snapshots/dev1/toree-pip/toree-0.2.0.dev1.tar.gz
jupyter toree install
```

I have Spark 2.2 and Anaconda in my PATH (not sure this is needed).
Python kernels notebooks work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!